# Visual C++ Undesired Result When UsingCreateProcess()

Tags: visual-c++

I'm building a Visual C++ console application and I need to execute another program located in same directory as the console application. I used CreateProcess() to start it.

```
VOID startup(LPCTSTR lpApplicationName, LPSTR args)
{
    // additional information
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // set the size of the structures
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // start the program up
    CreateProcess(lpApplicationName,   // the path
        args,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        );

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);       // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Ans this is the function call-

```
string command = "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Project\\Debug\\potrace.exe"; //the program to be executed
string arg = "-s -o \"" + libraryDir + "\\" + outputFileName + "\" -- \"" + tempDir + "\\" + tempFileName + "\""; //program arguments to be sent

char *args = new char[200];

for (int i = 0; args[i] = arg[i]; ++i); //converting std::string to char*

startup(command.c_str(), args);
```

The problem is that program being called produces different result when called from within the console application and when called from a command prompt. It generated an svg file but when called from application, this generated file is corrupt. If I copy the  value of `char *args` and use it as argument at command prompt, the output file is perfect and intact.

UPDATE: on opening the generated files I noticed that it's and EPS file, not an SVG file. This is very strange because the `-s` in `args` is for generating SVG file. Also, copying the value of `command.c_str()` and `args` and executing from command prompt does produce a valid SVG image. So why is the same command producing different result when called usign CreateProcess() and from command prompt?

UPDATE: if I modify `args` to include the program name too i.e., `potrace.exe <arguments>` and call startup using `startup(NULL, args)` then it runs perfectly. But I would still like to know the problem in the original approach.

Comment: What is the `Undesired result`?

Comment: Sorry, posted without mentioning the problem. I was just editing when you posted the comment.

Comment: Are you sure full command line fits into 100-character buffer?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik no I'm not sure but in testing the argument fit into a 100 character buffer. Anyways, I changed it to a 200 character buffer.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation for `CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) says:

> If both `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` are non-`NULL`, the null-terminated string pointed to by `lpApplicationName` specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by `lpCommandLine` specifies the command line.
>
> The new process can use `GetCommandLine` to retrieve the entire command line. Console processes written in C can use the `argc` and `argv` arguments to parse the command line. Because `argv[0]` is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line.

When a C or C++ program starts, the runtime calls `GetCommandLine` to get the command line used to invoke the program.  This is parsed to obtain the `argc` and `argv` to be passed to `main`.

If the program being spawned expects that the program name is in `argv[0]` and the "actual" arguments start with `argv[1]`, then you must ensure that you include the program name in the `lpCommandLine` passed to `CreateProcess` so that it is present in the command line string returned by `GetCommandLine` in the spawned process.